# Differentials of $f(x_1,x_2)=x^{x_1}_2.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Let $f:\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \vert x_2 >0 \} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $$f(x_1,x_2)=x^{x_1}_2.$$ Find the differentials $d^kf(1,1), k=0,1,2.$

I'm having trouble understanding the problem. By differentials do they mean all the partial derivatives or what? I remember seeing somewhere this corresponding to all the combinations of the partial derivatives or something? Any hints?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are being asked to compute [differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables) via $$df = \sum_{i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}} dx_{i}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two variables, the differential of a function is defined as
$$d^{n}f=\sum _{{k=0}}^{n}{\binom {n}{k}}{\frac {\partial ^{n}f}{\partial x^{k}\partial y^{{n-k}}}}(dx)^{k}(dy)^{{n-k}}$$
$f(x,y)=y^x$

for $k=0$, according to the definition, we have $d^0f(1,1)=1$

for $k=1$
$$df(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy=y^x \log (y)dx+x y^{x-1}dy$$
At point $(1,1)$ we have
$$df(1,1)=dy$$
for $k=2$
$$d^{2}f(x,y)=\left({\frac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}}(dx)^{2}+2{\frac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x\partial y}}dx\,dy+{\frac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial y^{2}}}(dy)^{2}\right)+{\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}}d^{2}x+{\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}}d^{2}y$$
$$d^2f(x,y)=y^x \log ^2(y)(dx)^2+2\left(y^{x-1}+x y^{x-1} \log (y)\right)dx\,dy+(x-1) x y^{x-2}(dy)^2+\\+y^x \log (y)d^2x+x y^{x-1}d^2y$$
$$d^2f(1,1)=2dx\,dy+d^2y$$

Comment: With $\frac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x\partial y}$ are you referring to taking the second partial of $x$ w.r.t to $y$ or the first partial?